# update-manager crashes on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: update-manager, ubuntu-mate

I noticed that my computer doesn't automatically get updated, also that whenever the software updater prompts me for new updates, it disappears when I click on it.

Running

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

works and updates correctly but when I run

```
update-manager
```

It crashes with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity

(update-manager:4386): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(update-manager:4386): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 253, in __del__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 887, in _find_spec
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I have this problem on two different laptops.
How can I fixt it?

Comment: Did you fix this error?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, started happening earlier this week (probably after an update).

Comment: I switched to Compiz via Mate-tweak earlier this week. I just switched back to Marco, and update-manager is working again. Are you using Compiz by any chance ?

Comment: Yes using Compiz @hatterman

Comment: Use marco, or no compositor as a quick test. Does it now work again ?

Comment: Curious, was Compiz the culprit ? (it is for me).

Comment: I think so, I remember I had it once work and I think it was oddly after Compiz crashed and Ubuntu switched back to Marco. Didn't have time to replicate it though as it isn't on my main computer.